# ReadTheDocs build fails due to pathspec

Tags: git, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I'm trying to [set up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65471557/make-html-not-working-for-sphinx-documentation-in-windows-10/65471768#65471768) a `sphinx` documentation and put it online using ReadTheDocs, however following the [steps of the tutorial](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro/getting-started-with-sphinx.html) I end up by having the following error pop in my build:

```
Read the Docs build information
Build id: 12647743
Project: documentationseries
Version: latest
Commit: None
Date: 2020-12-28T11:42:02.102474Z
State: finished
Success: False


[rtd-command-info] start-time: 2020-12-28T11:43:48.024647Z, end-time: 2020-12-28T11:43:48.412733Z, duration: 0, exit-code: 0
git clone --no-single-branch --depth 50 https://github.com/guilhermetheis/documentationSeries.git .
Cloning into '.'...

[rtd-command-info] start-time: 2020-12-28T11:43:48.872904Z, end-time: 2020-12-28T11:43:48.949867Z, duration: 0, exit-code: 1
git checkout --force master
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I've added the `.readthedocs.yml` as well. I had a `gitignore` that set the `build/` to be ignored, but this was removed as to my understanding the `build` folder contains the HTML code necessary. I haven't change anything on the `rst` side of the things yet. The idea was to make it go online and then add to remove any layer of complexity in the debugging. I really don't understand why this is happening (and I am quite new/bad on programming) so I kindly ask for in depth explanations if possible.

The [repository can be found here](https://github.com/guilhermetheis/documentationSeries)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The repo doesn't have a `master` branch so you obviously cannot check it out, `--force` or no `--force`.

The repo instead uses `main` as the name of the only branch, as you can easily discover by visiting the link you provided yourself.

(This is part of a grand renaming; many projects used `master` in the past but have now started migrating to a different terminology. See also [Difference Between Main Branch and Master Branch in Github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64249491/difference-between-main-branch-and-master-branch-in-github))

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea they migrated. I am now facing another problem, but should be related to sphinx/python and thus I need to create a new thread.

Comment: I got the same problem and it was supposed fixed https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/issues/7693

Comment: The change allows you to set `default_brarch` to something else, but you still have to set it; did you do that?